# e(fx)clipse css auto completion isn't working and unknown properties

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-css

I search the web and didn't find any sulution to help me.

I did tried to check all what that java related in the 'Content Assistent'.

I did tried to add css to the 'File Association', and I do have the JavaFX SDK

Furthermore, it's not detect any css fx property.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I Have seen this from the beginning (since I started using e(fx)clipse). My suspicion is that it isn't implementen (yet) since css properties are dynamic (e.i. Can change depending on the imported/used `Node`s). I usually follow [the reference page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) instead

Comment: Ok so there is no somthing that I can do to change it? and following a page is not so comfortable like the auto completion

Comment: Im afraid not. Luckly most common used properties can be found under `Node`, `Region` and `Shape`. Which is only three instead of a whole page. Besides, most properties are the same as 'regular css properties' only with the prefix `-fx-`.

Comment: I did learned in the past css and it is similer and the diffrents is only to add -fx- so this is very helpful. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Add javafx sdk library to the java build path

   **right click on your project -> properties -> Java build path -> libraries -> add 
     library -> javafx sdk**

   [see image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7kh0.png)
2. Configure e(fx)clipse like your default editor to css files.

   **windows -> preferences -> general -> editors -> file associations**

   [see image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JsHM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried every method like adding javafx sdk jars in buildpath. Adding file associations and text editor for css in Preferences but none of these worked.

At last I added this jar to build-path. It is located in the eclipse installation plugins folder:

> org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_3.5.0.201907240300.jar

and css code completion for javafx started working.